# Nothing happens using spawn gulp task to execute commands into subfolder

Tags: command-line, gulp, subdirectory, spawn

Yesterday, I've been sent to a reference to use process_child.spawn for my need. I'd like gulp executing commands for me, to avoid typing commands concerning my dependency when I need to compile my main project.

I got something that seems ok, any error into logs, but nothing happened, the way my commands wouldn't been executed.

Any one with feedback about my code ? I got another task like this one to compile the dependency.

```
        var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
        gulp.task("my-dependency-install", function(done) {
            spawn("ft", ["install"], {
                cwd: "node_modules/app/my-dependency/"
            })
                .on("error", function (err) {
                    throw err
                })
                .on("close", done);
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I've fixed it :

```
        var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
        spawn("ft.cmd", ["install"], {
            cwd: "node_modules/app/my-dependency/"
        })
            .on("error", function (err) {
                throw err
            });
```

Anyone is able to explain why I had to add .cmd ? It's because of windows OS, isn'it ?